# How can I print 2 lines if the second line contains the same match as the first line?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

Let's say I have a file with several million lines, organized like this:

```
@1:N:0:ABC
XYZ

@1:N:0:ABC
ABC
```

I am trying to write a one-line grep/sed/awk matching function that returns both lines if the `NCCGGAGA` line from the first line is found in the second line.

When I try to use `grep -A1 -P` and pipe the matches with a match like `'(?<=:)[A-Z]{3}'`, I get stuck. I think my creativity is failing me here.

Comment: So the expected output from your example would be nothing?

Comment: Well in this case... yes.  But there are a few thousand in there where the first sequence is found in the second line.

Comment: I don't really have any control over that. This is Illumina data from a shotgun genome. Technically, I am trying to clean it up by identifying these reads and cutting out the adapter sequence.

Comment: You have total control over the example that you post in the question, though!

Comment: Gotcha, cleaned it up a little

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `awk`

```
$ awk -F: 'NF==1 && $0 ~ s{print p ORS $0} {s=$NF; p=$0}' ip.txt
@1:N:0:ABC
ABC
```

- `-F:` use `:` as delimiter, makes it easy to get last column
- `s=$NF; p=$0` save last column value and entire line for printing later
- `NF==1` if line doesn't contain `:`
- `$0 ~ s` if line contains the last column data saved previously

  - if search data can contain regex meta characters, use `index($0,s)`  instead to search literally
- note that this code assumes input file having line containing `:` followed by line which doesn't have `:`

With `GNU sed` (might work with other versions too, syntax might differ though)

```
$ sed -nE '/:/{N; /.*:(.*)\n.*\1/p}' ip.txt
@1:N:0:ABC
ABC
```

- `/:/` if line contains `:`
- `N` add next line to pattern space
- `/.*:(.*)\n.*\1/` capture string after last `:` and check if it is present in next line

again, this assumes input like shown in question.. this won't work for cases like

```
@1:N:0:ABC
@1:N:0:XYZ
XYZ
```

Comment: This is wonderful, just out of curiosity -- how did you write this so fast? Do you use some kind of online regex tester? Most of the ones I come accross aren't that great.

Comment: I'd tried the solution before asking for example clarification in comments.. so after you posted the new sample, I added my solution as answer... I use Ubuntu and I have terminal open always.. so live testing ;) online testers are not good because [regex for tools vary in subtle and significant ways than those in programming languages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)...

Comment: @Sundeep: Why isn't there a `perl` answer yet ;)

Comment: @Inian didn't need it here ;) and it would be very similar to the awk one..

Answer (score 3):

If you actual Input_file is same as shown example then following may help you too here.

```
awk -v FS="[: \n]" -v RS="" '$(NF-1)==$NF'  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Adding 1 more solution as per Sundeep suggestion too here.

```
awk -v FS='[:\n]' -v RS= 'index($NF, $(NF-1))' Input_file
```

Comment: good idea if there are newlines between each data set.. OP's actual data would have something like `FHSABCES` in second line... so `awk -v FS='[:\n]' -v RS= 'index($NF, $(NF-1))'` would work :)

Comment: @Sundeep, thank you added that solution now to my post, cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'N;/.*:\(.*\)\n.*\1/p;D' file
```

Use *grep-like* option `-n` to explicitly print lines. Read two lines into the pattern space and print both if they meet the requirements. Always delete the first and repeat.

Comment: Very simple and elegant. I like it! I am still trying to decide if I should learn sed or awk more in-depth...

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves learn both! To get you started hover your cursor over the sed or awk tags at the top of the page (under the question) and follow the `info` link. Both GNU manuals are linked and more specialist resources can be found. Good Luck